# Where are the python picamera docs?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I installed the package `python-picamera-docs` successfully, with the command `sudo apt-get install python-picamera-docs`, on raspbian, but I can't actually find the docs.

I looked in `/usr/share/doc/python-picamera/`, and it just had a changelog and the copyright.

So where is the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to tell with:

```
dpkg -L python-picamera-docs
```

This will list the full path of all files installed by `python-picamera-docs`; you should be able to glance through that to find out where the actual docs are.

If `dpkg` is not installed, `sudo apt-get install dpkg`.

Comment: That path is: `/usr/share/doc/python-picamera-docs/html/index.html`! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The path is `/usr/share/doc/python-picamera-docs/html/index.html`. I found this thanks to @goldilocks.